# How do I vertical arrangement the element inside a UL element?

Tags: html, css

How can i, center the element without leaving the gap inside. I want the object (circle) to be moved -50% after the div and it was centered. Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIxtx.png unfortunately I can not solve it myself.

```css
.accordion,
[id^='list-'] {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  width: 480px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 72px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(185, 185, 0, 0.31);
  padding: 24px;
}

.circle {
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#d11, #25c);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="test">
    <ul class="accordion">
      <span class="post-meta">Mar 13, 2018</span>
      <h2 class="post-title">
        <a class="post-link no-underline" href="">Neque porro quisquam</a>
      </h2>
      <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="post-summary">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form...</p>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things that you need to target.

1. "without leaving the gap inside", By this line you mean that you need to reduce the space between the heading and the paragraph. So in order to do that you need to first know what is causing that space.

In our case there are multiple objects (`<h2>` & `<p>`) and their respective styles that are contributing to that space. So we go ahead and remove/reduce those `margin`s.

2. In order to align the circle to a outer container we need to remove it from the document flow by positioning it `absolute`ly and also set the position of the container `nav` to `relative` in order to confine the element's anchor origin to its boundary. Then manually position that element by setting the `left` attribute.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/QrWJeV)**

**Modified CSS:**

```css
.accordion {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
nav {
  width: 480px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 72px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(185, 185, 0, 0.31);
  padding: 24px;
  position:relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#d11, #25c);
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
}
.accordion h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
p.post-summary {
    padding-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
}
```

This should do what you're asking if I am understanding you correctly.